# Are FTP, httpd and NFS the only methods for setting up a Linux repo on a local network?

Tags: rhel, yum, repository

I'm planning on setting up a local offline Redhat 7 repo residing in a Docker container. Are FTP, httpd and NFS the only methods to give other systems on the local network access to the repo?

Comment: you can use FTP as well, e.g. https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/how-to-create-ftp-yum-repository-in-linux/

Comment: @Bart Yes, I forgot to list it as one of the options - right here in my notes. Thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: fair enough :) afaik, there are not much options, you could set up ssh tunel for yum repository, but that would not really be a secure option. other than that, HTTP/S is the standard, mostly

Comment: If NFS works by mounting and pointing to a file path on your local directory tree then Samba or any other file sharing protocol (even sshfs) could be used to make the share available and then mount it on the client.  When doing a fresh Debian install I often connect to my desktop machine's `/var/cache/apt/archives` to avoid re-downloading files.

Answer (score 0):

Red Hat does not support NFS for creating local repository. Although you can use NFS to mount remote server's repository on local client node and then use the respective mount point as a repo. But you cannot explicitly use NFS in repo file.

NFS is supported with SLES using zypper where you can directly give NFS path from the remove server.

You can also create a repo using ISO DVD or an offline repository.

Any service which helps you share your filesystem can be used to create a repo with RHEL as long as those shares are accessible on the localhost on the client.

Comment: Welcome to U&L! The answer box should answer the question; if you have questions to ask of the OP, the right thing to do is to comment on their question (available at 50 reputation points).

Comment: Also, instead of sending the reader off to different links, the idea here at Stack Exchange is to make answers self-explanatory. Please import any required information or steps from the links.

Comment: Sorry folks, thanks for the comment. Will try to consider these points in my future posts.